# How do I set the meta-language in the Racket REPL?

Tags: racket

I have a program that uses the [at-exp](https://docs.racket-lang.org/scribble/reader-internals.html#%28mod-path._at-exp%29) meta-language:

```
#lang at-exp racket
(define v '@f{str})
(displayln v)
```

I want to manually type it line-by-line into the Racket REPL. Unfortunately, `#lang at-exp racket` is not valid in the REPL:

```
$ racket
Welcome to Racket v6.11.
> #lang at-exp racket
; readline-input:1:0: read: #lang not enabled in the current context [,bt for
;   context]
; at-exp: undefined;
;  cannot reference undefined identifier
; [,bt for context]
; racket: undefined;
;  cannot reference undefined identifier
; [,bt for context]
>
```

How do I set the meta-language in the Racket REPL?

Comment: In my understanding (which I'd be glad to be proven wrong), this is right now not feasible.

Comment: @SoraweePorncharoenwase Not even by using a command line option? The `-I` command line option sets the programming language. Is there an option that sets the meta-language?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the beginners who have ended up here, the short answer is no. The [#lang shorthand](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Module_Syntax.html#%28part._hash-lang%29) should only be used in files. If you want to run your example program in the REPL, you could load it using this command.

```
racket --repl --eval '(enter! (file "your-file.rkt"))'
```

The more detailed answer is that the [#lang shorthand](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Module_Syntax.html#%28part._hash-lang%29) gets re-written behind the scenes into [module form](https://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/Module_Syntax.html#%28part._module-syntax%29).

So for example something like this...

```lisp
#lang racket
(define v "Hello!")
(displayln v))
```

Is re-written to what you see below and you could copy and paste this into the repl and then require the module, e.g. in the repl type...

```lisp
> (module the-hello-module racket
    (define v "Hello!")
    (displayln v))
> (require 'the-hello-module)
Hello!
```

But from what I can tell, that re-write is dependent on the languages you're using, so the rewrite is probably not something you want to do manually and I don't think the `at-exp` metalanguage is something you would be add manually to module form.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why they're different, but the REPL inside DrRacket can use the `#lang` shorthand:

> Unlike the command-line REPL, the DrRacket REPL adopts the language spec­i­fied by the #lang line at the top of the defi­n­i­tions panel. DrRacket also uses the REPL itself to print output from the program.

https://beautifulracket.com/explainer/repl.html#a_Rv5YS

So if you have `#lang at-exp racket/base` in the definitions panel and click "Run" the bottom REPL panel will show `Language: at-exp racket/base`, etc., and this will work:

```lisp
> @string-append{this is a test}
"this is a test"
```

That page also says:

> More intri­cate REPL hacking is possible. For instance, the REPL can be config­ured to use a custom reader (other than Racket’s default S-expres­sion reader).
> https://beautifulracket.com/basic-3/the-repl.html

However, the steps described there are much more involved than I care to get into.  I don't know what DrRacket is doing in the background to make `#lang at-exp` work.